# Figure out section of a section header when tapped in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom views for section headers. I added a UITapGestureRecognizer to the customer sections header views to detect when someone has tapped on a section header.

How do I figure out which section the section headers belong to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to designate a property on your section header view class to hold the section index, then assign the index to that property in `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // CustomHeaderView *headerView = ...

    headerView.section = section;

    // ...
    return headerView;
}
```

Then have the gesture callback look at that property.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have tried. However, when I insert a new section into the middle of the table, all the section numbers are out of sync. Any tips to overcome this?

Comment: Hmm, in that case, see if calling [`-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections:withRowAnimation:) after adding sections helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `action` method that you are providing must have the [following signature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) :

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

And a `gestureRecognizer` have the following properties :

> Getting the Recognizer’s State and View
>     state  property
>     view  property
>     enabled  property

So basically you can ask for the view that it is attached to and interrogate that view.

Answer (score 1):

in the viewDidLoad section insert your gestureRecognizer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    (...)

    UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapTable:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.yourTable addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

    (...)

}
```

If you only want to detect single tap change doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired to 1.

Then add the following method. This will check if the tapped point is inside section header:

```
-(void)doubleTapTable:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state)
    {
        CGPoint p = [tap locationInView:tap.view];

        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [yourTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];

        if(indexPath){  // user taped a cell

            // whatever you want to do if user taped cell

        } else { // otherwise check if section header was clicked 

            NSUInteger i;

            for(i=0;i<[yourTable numberOfSections];i++) {

                CGRect headerViewRect = [yourTable rectForHeaderInSection:i];

                BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint (headerViewRect,
                                                     p);
                if(isInside) {

                    // handle Header View Selection

                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here, but this can be a difficult problem to solve, especially if (as @klyngbaek mentions in the comments), you are adding/removing sections.  Changing a tag or custom index property on the header `UIView` by reloading entire sections can result in ugly animations.

Try this as a callback method for the gesture recognizer that's attached to each header `UIView` (admittedly hackey):

```
- (void)headerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{

    NSInteger section = 0;
    for(int counter = 0; counter < [self.tableViewOfInterest numberOfSections]; counter++){
        if([[self.tableViewOfInterest headerViewForSection:counter] frame].origin.y == sender.view.frame.origin.y){
            section = counter;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, when asking a `UITableView` for each section header, it returns an instance of the header with the frame set to the header's position in the table.  Comparing this with the frame of the `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s `view` property will result in a match at some point (no pun intended)!

Answer (score 0):

You can add button to header and set tag to button something like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:
(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.height, tableView.frame.size.width)];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];
    button.tag = section;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(detectSection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubView:button];
    return headerView;
}

-(void)detectSection:(UIButton *)sender {
    switch(sender.tag) {
    //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.